# sqlite select minimum and maximum from two tables

Tags: sqlite, max, min

I have two tables

table1

```
c1t1    c2t1
1       saanu
3       abc
```

table2

```
c1t2    c2t2
2       val2
4       val4
```

I have to find out the values of c2t1 and c2t2 for the minimum and maximum value of c1t1 and c1t2 with one line command.

For the above example I have to find saanu and val4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
select max(case c1 when min1 then c2 end) c2_first, 
       max(case c1 when max1 then c2 end) c2_last 
from (select c1t1 c1, c2t1 c2 from table1
       union all
       select c1t2 c1, c2t2 c2 from table2) u
cross join
(select min(min11, min12) min1, max(max11, max12) max1 from
 (select min(c1t1) min11, max(c1t1) max11 from table1) t1
 cross join
 (select min(c1t2) min12, max(c1t2) max12 from table2) t2) m
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b517a/6).

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem and solved it with UNION ALL. The minimum of the aColumn column in tables aTable1, ... , aTableN can be computed as:

```
SELECT Min(aColumn) 
FROM (
SELECT aColumn FROM aTable1 UNION ALL
SELECT aColumn FROM aTable2 UNION ALL
...
SELECT aColumn FROM aTableN) t;
```

You should be able to do Min in each of the inner selects, but I haven't found out how to do that!

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
SELECT c2t1
FROM table1
ORDER BY c1t1 ASC LIMIT 1
```

2)

```
SELECT c2t2
FROM talbe2
ORDER BY c1t2 DESC LIMIT 1
```